# Not able to add row data correctly

Tags: python, excel, file, csv, row

```
def csv_report(rec_id,msg1):
    with open('mycsv.csv', 'a',newline='') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow({rec_id,msg1})
```

I used this function to write data in csv file having two fields but i am getting the output like in rec_id iam getting msg1 and in place of msg1 iam getting rec_id.
Attaching the output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jepf3.png)

Comment: Typo: use a list: `[rec_id,jsg1]`.  What you have is an unordered set: `{rec_id,msg1}`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. It may be the code that is supplying the `csv_report()` function. Below is a generic function you can use for appending/creating any csv from dictionary data:

```
import csv


def append_csv_dict(path, data):
    '''
    Append a csv with a dictionary keys as column headers

    Args:
        path (str): Path to the csv file
        data (dict): Dictionary with keys as column headers
                     and values as column data
    '''
    with open(path, 'a') as file:
        # set the field names to the keys of the dictionary
        fieldnames = list(data.keys())
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        # write the header if the file is new
        if file.tell() == 0:
            writer.writeheader()
        # write the row
        writer.writerow(data)

# write some of the names to the file
append_csv_dict('mycsv.csv', {'email': 'michael.lawson@reqres.in', 'message': 'Editor role has been enabled'})
append_csv_dict('mycsv.csv', {'email': 'lidsay.ferguson@reqres.in', 'message': 'Person already has editor access'})
append_csv_dict('mycsv.csv', {'email': 'tobias.funke@reqres.in', 'message': 'Editor role has been enabled'})
append_csv_dict('mycsv.csv', {'email': 'byron.fields@reqres.in', 'message': 'Person Account Created and ...'})
append_csv_dict('mycsv.csv', {'email': 'george.edwards@reqres.in', 'message': 'Person Account Created and ...'})
append_csv_dict('mycsv.csv', {'email': 'rachel.howell@reqres.in', 'message': 'Person Account Created and ...'})
```

Output:

```
email,message
michael.lawson@reqres.in,Editor role has been enabled
lidsay.ferguson@reqres.in,Person already has editor access
tobias.funke@reqres.in,Editor role has been enabled
byron.fields@reqres.in,Person Account Created and ...
george.edwards@reqres.in,Person Account Created and ...
rachel.howell@reqres.in,Person Account Created and ...
```